# Cannot paste from clipboard into a TMemo

Tags: delphi, clipboard, tmemo

I have a client that reports he cannot paste into a TMemo from the clipboard. I also have code that calls TMemo.PasteFromClipboard, but this does not work.

He is using Windows 8 (not sure if 8.0 or 8.1).

Other users in their office do not experience this problem.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

(Application developed with Delphi 7)

Comment: What about other applications (such as Windows Notepad)? Do they work? I've seen a similar issue and it came down to some software which was spontaneously copying something to the clipboard without knowledge (overwriting what was already there). Once that program was terminated, everything worked.

Comment: Yes, I asked him to copy from Word to Notepad and it did work ok. What was that program?

Comment: I'm not at liberty to say, but it appears it's problems with Windows 8/8.1.

Comment: Is it just your button, or does right-click|paste fail as well?

Comment: @Chris: The popup which includes the paste button overrides the default right click menu, so I cannot say. It seemed that both ctrl+v and my paste button failed.

Comment: @moskito-x, I have not got more info yet. I will post back when I get more info.

Comment: @RaelB : how far you come ? My Answer could help you?

Comment: @RaelB : now one year later my Answer could help you?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 / 8.1 : copy and paste, known problem since 2013

- copy content lost, switching from one app to another app.
- try to copy and paste anything to an email.
- trouble with copy and paste between a virtual machine and desktop.
- copy-and-paste takes several tries.
- using arrow keys when `NUM` is on (deletes Clipboard content).

Sometimes could be solved with

- disabling the "Send to Bluetooth" option in Outlook.
  To disable the Add-in, start Outlook with the "Run As Administrator" option.

OR

- Disabling C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Bluetooth\btmoffice.dll in the COM Add-in manager.

IE Internet Options

Allow Programatic clipboard access.

- Switch from `Disabled` to `Prompt`

Sometimes set to Disabled make problems.

---

Webroot, if your client using **webroot**

- Ask client to add your App to `Application Protection tab`

Win8, Webroot Secure Anywhere Internet Security Plus

- Open Webroot as Admin user.
- Identity Protection properties (gear icon).
- Application Protection tab.
  list of applications (three radio buttons) : Protect, Allow or Deny.
  Look for the application that does not allow you to cut/copy/paste.
  If it's set to "Deny" you won't be able to use cut/copy/paste.

[SecureAnywhere, ManagingProtectedApps](http://www.webroot.com/En_US/SecureAnywhere/PC/WSA_PC_Help.htm#C6_IDProtection/CH6c_ManagingProtectedApps.htm)

Comment: Thanks, do you have some type of official reference to this problem?

Comment: @RaelB : Unfortunately I have not found any official site for this problem. But many links to copy paste problem in Windows 8.

Comment: @RaelB : look at my answer about **webroot**